# How to use a tri-state checkbox/TreeItem in Java?

Tags: java, checkbox, rcp, java-6

Env: Java SE 6

I am working on an Eclipse RCP application. How do I create TreeItems with tri-state checkbox. Like the Eclipse IDE update package interface. I use SWT TreeItem class now, which only provides API, setChecked(bool), for true/false states.

[image]

Comment: One more question, where could be the setGrayed code located? I looked into InstallWizard.class, SelectableIUsPage.class, CheckboxTableViewer.class but found nothing related. My intention was to find out how they handle the partial selection and update the parent node with setGrayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filled in check box is known as 'grayed'.

With `CheckboxTreeViewer` use the `setGrayed`, `setGrayChecked`, `setGrayedElements` methods to set grayed items.

With `TreeItem` use the `setGrayed` method.

It is up to you to code the logic for determining when a node should be grayed.

Comment: @grep-449, does Swing framework provide APIs to handle the tri-state checkbox? Or I would need to traverse the sibling nodes and setGrayed for the parent node myself? It seems there should be something there taking care of this task.

Comment: This is SWT not Swing. Eclipse does not use Swing.

Comment: OK, I got it wrong. But the question is the same - do I need to do the plumbing work to check isAllSiblingsChecked, then setParentGrayed myself?

Comment: I don't know of any standard code to handle the gray state.